# Adding extra statements in a python list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a requirement to find a line in a text file which contains a specific string and then append that line and all lines that follow it to a list. This is the way I accomplished it..

```
file1 = open("input.txt", "r")
always_print = False
lines = file1.readlines()
output = []
for line in lines:
    if always_print or "def set" in line:  #def set is the string i want
        output.append(line)
        always_print = True
```

While this works fine,I tried doing the same using list comprehensions.This is what i got :

```
lines = [ item.strip() for item in open("input.txt")]
always_print = False
output = [item for item in lines if "def set" or print_always in item]
```

This obviously does not work as I don't set the always_print=True when the desired string is found.How do i do that within the list comprehension ??

Comment: @Cyber my bad, I kinda just read the `output = ...` line… to be honest.

Comment: You *can't* put sentences (like your assignment `always_print = True`) in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`itertools.dropwhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.dropwhile) to find the first line that contains your `def set`:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

output = list(dropwhile(lambda l: 'def set' not in l, lines))
```

`dropwhile()` will skip any entry in `lines` that doesn't match your test; as soon as it matches it stops testing and simply yields everything from there on out.

`dropwhile()` returns an iterator; I used `list()` here to convert it to a list of lines, but you could use it as a basis for another loop too, like stripping of newlines, etc.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import dropwhile
>>> lines = '''\
... foo
... bar
... def set():
...     spam
...     ham
...     eggs
... '''.splitlines(True)
>>> list(dropwhile(lambda l: 'def set' not in l, lines))
['def set():\n', '    spam\n', '    ham\n', '    eggs\n']
```

Comment: this is really nice..just what I needed..so just to understand,can I conclude that python does not support extra statements within list comprehensions ?

Comment: @Amistad Correct. A list comprehension is an expression, and *no* expression can contain a statement.

Comment: @Amistad: In Python, a list comprehension is an expression. Expressions can be nested as much as you like, but statements are top-level components and cannot be nested inside one another or in expressions. Assignment is a statement, you cannot use that in an expression.

Comment: @Amistad: you'd have to use another mutable object whose state you can change with methods, but that gets ugly fast. And here a `dropwhile()` expresses what happens much better.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit** Correcting from my previous completely incorrect answer:

Not that I would use this in production code, but hacking away at it, you *can* do it in a list comprehension...

```
always_print = []
output = [item for item in lines 
          if always_print
          or (always_print.append(1) if ("def set" in item) else None) 
          or "def set" in item]
```

Just to explain, the second of three conditions always returns `None` which is a Falsy value.

Slipping further into the darkside, if you didn't want to evaluate `"def set" in item` twice:

```
always_print = []
output = [item for item in lines 
          if always_print
          or (
              (always_print.append(1) or True) if ("def set" in item) else False
             )]
```

**Edit2**

If I describe what's going on here in more detail...

The code above (and Kevin's, mentioned in his comment) uses three separate tricks.

1. In Python, most objects and values have an associated Boolean.  e.g. 0 is `False`, any other number is `True`.  In the same vein, an empty list is `False` while a non-empty list is evaluated as `True`.
2. While variable assignment like a=1 does not return any value and cannot be included as part of a list comprehension, `a_list.append(x)` is a function call and returns `None` which is evaluated as `False`.  It also has the side-effect of adding the new element `x` to the end of `a_list`.
3. Logical operators like `and` and `or` have evaluation order from left to right. `and` stops execution at the first `False` value and `or` stops at the first `True` value, which can be used to control whether the list appending gets executed or not based on certain conditions.  The ternary operator 'x if y else z' also has evaluation order, but evaluates 'y' first then either 'x' or 'z' but never both.

As you can see, a set of very roundabout logic tricks that may have their place in ultra-optimized C (or the [IOCCC](http://ioccc.org/)), but not Python.  It's *possible* to replicate your control flow within a list comprehension, but in practical terms, use `dropwhile` every time.

Comment: So does this modify the `always_print` value partway through the loop like the original code does?

Comment: Interesting approach. I was thinking of something along the same lines: `output = [line for line in lines if always_print or "def set" in line and not always_print.append(1)]`. Works on roughly the same "conditional mutation" principle.

Comment: Ah that's much more elegant, in a dark way.

Comment: Kevin and zehnprad..trying to understand..what does always_print.append(1) do ? Is always_print not a boolean ? Can we append to it like a list ?

Answer (score 0):

Drop while is probably the best solution. But if you want something really fancy, have a look at the following:

Using list comprehensions you can use simple checks and transformations, but you should see a list comprehension more like a mathematical mapping. You could, however, give the function you use to test if an item should be included some kind of state i.e. make your check remember if something has already occurred. Make it a functor (or function object):

```
class Drop_before:
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.val = val
    self.always_print = False
  def __call__(self, current_val):
    if current_val == self.val:
      self.always_print = True
    return self.always_print

drop_before_6 = Drop_before(6)
print [x for x in xrange(10) if drop_before_6(x)]
#using filter
print filter(Drop_before(4), xrange(10))
```

which outputs:

```
[6, 7, 8, 9]
[4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```